# Installing PHP library for Supervisor using composer

Tags: php, supervisord

I want to use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to manager my processes. I have got it installed on my Amazon linux Machine and the basic setup runs fine as per the config file.

Now, I want to change the processes dynamically. Since it needs the config file to be changed every time and a restart, using PHP library to do the same seems to be a good option.

Specifically I am going through [SupervisorPHP config](https://github.com/supervisorphp/configuration) to change the configuration dynamically and [SupervisorPHP](https://github.com/supervisorphp/supervisor) to manager Supervisor through PHP.

Following the README for [SupervisorPHP config](https://github.com/supervisorphp/configuration), I got it installed via composer

```
composer require supervisorphp/configuration
```

I copied the sample code

```
<?php
    use Supervisor\Configuration\Configuration;
    use Supervisor\Configuration\Section\Supervisord;
    use Supervisor\Configuration\Section\Program;
    use Indigophp\Ini\Rendere;

    $config = new Configuration;
    $renderer = new Renderer;

    $section = new Supervisord(['identifier' => 'supervisor']);
    $config->addSection($section);

    $section = new Program('test', ['command' => 'cat']);
    $config->addSection($section);

    echo $renderer->render($config->toArray());
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Supervisor\Configuration\Configuration' not found in test.php on line 7
```

I also tried to clone the repo and include the files individually, however it shows error for other dependencies. It would be great if I could use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in the above code.

The first mistake is that you do not use the autoloader provided by composer so that php can find the necessary classes. To do so just add `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` (If the vendor folder is in a different path relative to the sample script then adjust accordingly).

The second mistake is in the use statement for Indigophp. Apart from the obvious typo in the word Renderer, if you check the source of Indigo you will see that it must be `use Indigo\Ini\Renderer;`

So the correct code to test your installation is:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Supervisor\Configuration\Configuration;
use Supervisor\Configuration\Section\Supervisord;
use Supervisor\Configuration\Section\Program;
use Indigo\Ini\Renderer;

$config = new Configuration;
$renderer = new Renderer;

$section = new Supervisord(['identifier' => 'supervisor']);
$config->addSection($section);

$section = new Program('test', ['command' => 'cat']);
$config->addSection($section);

echo $renderer->render($config->toArray());
```

Running the above code, you should get the following output:

```
[supervisord]
identifier = supervisor

[program:test]
command = cat
```